# redirect old PHPBB link to new link structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forum, phpbb

I have an old PHPB forum with a lot of posts with links to other posts that look like this:
http://link.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=1628&p=9062#p9062
Now the problem is that the new forum is at /forum so the link should be:
http://link.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=1628&p=9062#p9062

Is there any way to automaticaly redirect the user, using .htacces for example? but only when viewtopic.php gets accesed?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `RedirectPermanent /viewtopic.php /forum/viewtopic.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/viewtopic.php(.*) /forum/viewtopic.php$1 [R=301]
```